# remove meta tag or replace in next js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, meta-tags

I am using the service https://reqbin.com/curl and it says that I have an error because of the capital letter in the tag attribute.

```
The attribute name of [ charSet ] must be in lowercase
```

I tried to add a tag in the head tag hoping that it would be replaced, but it is not replaced, how can I remove the tag with a capital letter? Next.js adds this tag itself, how can I prevent it from adding it?
[image][image]

Comment: Seems to be an "issue" caused by react, while it is debated if this is a "bug" or not: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21571